# Form being not submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, email, http-post

I have a simple html form that should be using POST method to submit the form and it will send form contents on mail.php to send email. I have verified the php mail functionality working on server using the following code:

```
  $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com'; mail('myemail@mail.com', 'test email yo', 'This is a test email message', $headers, '-fwebmaster@example.com');
```

the PHP code I'm using to send the mail is as follows:

```
mail('myemail@mail.com', $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['message']);
```

the html form that should be sending the info is this:

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" method="post" action="mail.php">
    <div class="success-message">Contact form submitted.</div>
    <div class="coll-1">
        <p class="mbot3">Name*</p>
        <label class="name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters" name="name"/>
            <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
            <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid name.</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="coll-2">
        <p class="mbot3">E-mail*</p>
        <label class="email">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" data-constraints="@Required @Email" name="email"/>
            <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
            <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid email.</span>
        </label>
     </div>
     <div class="coll-3">
         <p class="mbot3">Phone</p>
         <label class="phone">
             <input type="text" placeholder="" data-constraints="@JustNumbers" name="phone"/>
             <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
             <span class="error-message">*This is not a valid phone.</span>
         </label>
      </div>
      <label class="message">
          <span class="mbot3">Message*</span>
          <textarea placeholder="" data-constraints="@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)" name="message"></textarea>
          <span class="empty-message">*This field is required.</span>
          <span class="error-message">*The message is too short.</span>
       </label>
   <div>
      <a href="#" data-type="submit" class="btn-link btn-link1"><img src="img/arrow1.png" alt="">submit</a>
      <p class="req">* Required fields</p>
   </div>
</form>
```

I can't get the contents of the form to come through in the email, I'm assuming possibly wrongly that the issue is with the form and it's ability to POST the info to php?

This code is from a premade template I did not write it myself.

Edit: As suggested I added the name attributes however that has not fixed the issue. Updated HTML to reflect current code.

Edit2: Have solved problem, I had to remove id="contact-form" not sure what was associated with this that was preventing the form submitting but that did it. From there I took the styles from the original form and added them to a new id that I replaced it with.

Comment: give name attribute to input type like this <input type="text" placeholder="" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters"  name="first_name"/>  and then try to get that name in $_POST

Comment: try to add **name** in all input type like <input type="text" placeholder="" name="name" ....

Comment: Only one change @NIMESHPATEL name="name" not name="first_name" as he is receiving as $_POST['name']

Comment: You can test the form posting in mail.php by using print_r($_POST); But some other things to do when you have that working: check your mail() function the second time as the parameters are different from your test (and wrong). Also also verify input (posted data) before using it to strip out newline characters and other nasties that will update sendMail.

Comment: yes  name is keyword so I suggested him first_name @PassionInfinite

Comment: Ohh! got it! @NIMESHPATEL :)

Answer (score 3):

You missed the **name** to the **input and textarea** field

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters"  name = "name"/>
```

The **name attribute** should have the **same** name as you are receiving from **$_POST['name']**

Comment: I added the name attributes but the email still not coming through.

Comment: Change the input type= text to email for email.

Comment: I've added this and still no dice.

Comment: Okay just add print_r($_POST) in the mail.php and show me its output. @benikens

Answer (score 0):

Check these fields on your `HTML` code,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters" />
<input type="text" placeholder="" data-constraints="@Required @Email" />
<input type="text" placeholder="" data-constraints="@JustNumbers"/>
<textarea placeholder="" data-constraints="@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)"></textarea>
```

And replace them with following code, you missed to add `name` attribute, `name` attribute used to reference form data after you submit the form.

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" data-constraints="@Required @JustLetters" />
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="" data-constraints="@Required @Email" />
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="" data-constraints="@JustNumbers"/>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="" data-constraints="@Required @Length(min=20,max=999999)"></textarea>
```